# See if an integer in an array is divisible by another and print c#

Tags: c#, arrays, 2d, division

I need to create a method that takes a 2d array as an argument to find out what numbers are divisible by 4 or 7. The array of integers  are 1- 100 in a 2d array in c#.

this is what i got

```
public void DivisbleBy4And7(int[,] pNumberMatrix)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            if (pNumberMatrix[i, j] % 4 || pNumberMatrix[i,j] % 7)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(pNumberMatrix[i,j];
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }
        }
    }      
}
```

Comment: and the question is? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: I assume, that your code is not working?

Comment: Please avoid hungarian notation for public C# sample code. Also try to name you methods in a way that reflect what they do OR match code to method name - name is `DivisbleBy4And7` but for some reason you use `||` (or) operator in the condition.

Comment: You shouldn't have the `for` loops both go to `10`, you should have them go to the size of that dimension of the array.  As is you can only pass in 10x10 arrays, instead of any array, and there's no indication of this restriction on the caller.

Answer (score 3):

You are close already.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
```

This only works for 10x10 arrays, consider

```
    for (int i = 0; i < pNumberMatrix.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < pNumberMatrix.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
```

C# does not convert from `int` to `bool`, and furthermore divisibility requires that `%` yields `0`. So

```
        // if (pNumberMatrix[i, j] % 4 || pNumberMatrix[i,j] % 7) 
           if ((pNumberMatrix[i, j] % 4) == 0 || (pNumberMatrix[i,j] % 7) == 0)
            {
```

Comment: I can't spell anymore. Blame it on IntelliSense.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you must write :

```
public void DivisbleBy4And7(int[,] pNumberMatrix)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            if (pNumberMatrix[i, j] % 4 == 0 || pNumberMatrix[i,j] % 7 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(pNumberMatrix[i,j];
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }
        }
    }      
}``
```

Comment: Joey Saxon I glad to help you. If my answer is correct, accept it)

Comment: All I would fix is the `for` loops.  They only do `10x10` arrays??

Comment: @justderb yes only for arrays 10*10, but maybe author want that, as he says: "The array of integers are 1- 100 in a 2d array in c#. " .

Comment: @AramGevorgyan If this is true, then I would probably put in size checks so that no unexpected Exceptions get thrown.

Comment: @justderb Yes you write it's better to write this way. But it doesn't answer the question and it isn't so important. Maybe author call this method only once and he is sure that he passes correct array.